# error:not enough internal storage

Tags: internal-storage

I have 12 GB remaining on my SD card and 200 mb remaining in my phone storage than also when I went to install a 800KB app then it says "low internal space" in my phone geoniee M2 and have android jelly bean 4.2.2

Comment: try cleaning applications like clean-master https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quite a common problem for some users.

Try this out...

- go to settings
- then go to apps section
- then go to all apps section
- find google play store
- click on clear cache

Hope this will work...